# How can I make a multiline label in a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

How can we make the text in the label of a table view go to the next line?

Answer (score 27):

```
//This allows for multiple lines
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
//This makes your label wrap words as they reach the end of a line
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

Also, if you want your label to have more room for such multiple lines, you probably should allow for table rows with greater height. You can do this either by overriding

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and returning your custom height for each row there, or by specifying your table's `rowHeight` property, giving the common height of each row.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding "\n" in the label, eg:

```
@"Hello,\nworld!"
```

Comment: The label must also be configured to allow multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use cell with subtitle( initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle ). if it is not exactly what you want, you can customize your cell by adding UITextView(or, maybe, several UILabels) to it as a subView(s).